# Unable to lock chain (Insufficient port permissions)

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, intel-fpga

I am new to Linux , and I am trying to install AlteraQuartus 2 WEb Edition and NIOS2 EDS to play with Nios2 Processor.

However , after installing Quartus and when I am trying to execute jtagconfig.

I do not see something like below , even after running /altera/nios2eds/nios2_command_shell.sh

*1.)[Nios2 EDS] $ 
2.)   Unable to lock chain (Insufficient port permissions)*

Please Help,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Insufficient permissions" or "permission denied" or whatever relating to not having permissions on *nix *usually* means you must run the command as user `root` (or as another user who has the permissions, but `root` has all of them).

So run `jtagconfig` as `root`:

```
$ sudo jtagconfig
```

Alternatively, as root, put this in a new file `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-altera-usb-blaster.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="09fb", ATTR{idProduct}=="6001", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="09fb", ATTR{idProduct}=="6002", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="09fb", ATTR{idProduct}=="6003", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="09fb", ATTR{idProduct}=="6010", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="09fb", ATTR{idProduct}=="6810", MODE="0666"
```

and then, run:

```
$ sudo udevadm control --reload
```

This should change the permission of your USB-Blaster Download Cable device so that any user may access it (if this is what you want), so you should be able to issue `jtagconfig` without `sudo`. Those five `idProduct`s are all the known USB-Blaster Download Cable USB product IDs (for the Altera vendor ID, `0x09fb`).

I wrote a fairly complete [Arch Linux wiki page about Altera softwares on Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Altera_Design_Software) if you want more details.

Comment: Please don't recommend running commands like this as root (it's not only a security problem, a tool which leaves log files behind may then block the user from overwriting those); granting permission to the device node as in the second half of your post is far more appropriate.

Comment: `jtagd` should be killed before starting `jtagconfig` as root, otherwise, if `jtagd` is already running as user, it will continue to do so and starting `jtagconfig` as root will have no effect. I took the liberty of posting a separate answer.

Answer (score 10):

To check if this is indeed a port permission problem, start the trouble-shooting by running `jtagd` (the deamon between the Altera tool and the driver) as root. At first, you must make sure that `jtagd` is not running, since if it is already running as a user, trying to start it as root will have no effect.

```
$ sudo killall -9 jtagd   # Kill jtagd, ...
$ sudo killall -9 jtagd   # ...and verify jtagd is indeed not running.
jtagd: no process found   # Good, verified.
$ sudo jtagconfig         # Will also start jtagd as root
1) CV SoCKit [2-1]
  02D020DD   5CSEBA6(.|ES)/5CSEMA6/..
  4BA00477   SOCVHPS
```

If the above is successful, this is indeed a port permission problem. To fix it permanently, try with udev rules, as suggested by @eepp.

(On a side note, `jtagd` will be started by `jtagconfig` if not already running, as the same user that started `jtagd`. Hence @eepps command will work as well, but `jtagd` should be killed first.)

For further trouble-shooting, running `jtagd` with some debug command-line options can give useful information:

```
$ jtagd --foreground --debug
JTAG daemon started
Using config file /etc/jtagd/jtagd.conf
Remote JTAG permitted when password set
Cant bind to TCP port 1309 - exiting
```

(The above error message is typical if `jtagd` is already running.)

(Above is taken från http://www.fpga-dev.com/altera-usb-blaster-with-ubuntu/. See that page for more details.)

Comment: My environment is Quartus Prime 15.1  + Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.     `sudo killall -9 jtagd` works.

Answer (score 0):

It may be obvious but make sure you're not going through a USB hub. That was my problem for Altera DE2-115 with Quartus Prime Lite 20.1.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.
The above answers fixed my permissions issue (Specifically adding `ATTR{idVendor}=="09fb", ATTR{idProduct}=="6001", MODE="0666"` to the new file  `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-altera-usb-blaster.rules`).

But I was still getting.

```
1) USB-Blaster [1-2.1]
  unable to lock chain - Chain in use - check
```

Going straight to my PC solved it.